# Go http.FileServer is not serving all static content

Tags: go

I have an api that I generated with go-swagger.  Then, I implemented middleware to be able to serve up my swagger UI for specific paths. However, it is only serving the index.html file in my swagger-ui directory so the UI does not function as it's missing all the other javascipt, etc.

I just can't seem to figure out what is going on and why it isn't serving them up. I could certainly use some help if anyone has any ideas.

**My File Structure:**

```
 /api-project   
   cmd
     main.go   
   gen   
   swagger-ui
     index.html
     swagger.json
     swagger-ui.css
     favicon-16x16.png
     ...
```

**Middleware to serve up the static swagger-ui site:**

```
func UIMiddleware(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        // Shortcut helpers for swagger-ui
        if r.URL.String() == "/swagger-ui" || r.URL.String() == "/api/help" {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/swagger-ui/", http.StatusFound)
            return
        }
        // Serving ./swagger-ui/
        if r.URL.String() == "/swagger-ui/" {
            Logger.Printf("Serving up SwaggerUI")
            http.StripPrefix("/swagger-ui/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("swagger-ui"))).ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Comment: Look at r.URL.Path instead of r.URL.String(). r.URL.String() is the full URL, with http://hostname/path

Comment: @bserdar - That fixed it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modified my code as follows. It now works.

```
func UIMiddleware(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        // Shortcut helpers for swagger-ui
        if r.URL.Path == "/swagger-ui" || r.URL.Path == "/api/help" {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/swagger-ui/", http.StatusFound)
            return
        }
        // Serving ./swagger-ui/
        if strings.Index(r.URL.Path, "/swagger-ui/") == 0 {
            Logger.Printf("Serving up SwaggerUI")
            http.StripPrefix("/swagger-ui/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("swagger-ui"))).ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```